# Sorting aggregated data in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am doing a search that is doing an aggregation by xyz field and getting the latest version. Now I need to sort the aggregated data based on created field. Let me know how we can do that.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": ""
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "uuid": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "xyz.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_trades_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "version": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the Above mentioned query returns

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "uuid": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "794a5b8f-3e22-4ff9-98bb-b8b54c85948e",
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "agg": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 3,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "index",
                                    "_type": "doc",
                                    "_id": "7",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "uuid": "794a5b8f-3e22-4ff9-98bb-b8b54c85948e",
                                        "type": "qsdn",
                                        "discontinued": false,
                                        "minSupportedPlatformVersion": "11.5.3.3",
                                        "version": 2,
                                        "created": 1658428291346
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        2
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "03504029-a029-417d-bd67-fb1b5fc5055b",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "agg": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "index",
                                    "_type": "doc",
                                    "_id": "9",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "uuid": "03504029-a029-417d-bd67-fb1b5fc5055b",
                                        "type": "gdsg",
                                        "discontinued": false,
                                        "version": 1.1,
                                        
                                        "created": 1554904300799
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1.1
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Document for the elastic search is as follows

```
{
    "_index": "index",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_version": 2,
    "_seq_no": 1,
    "_primary_term": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "doc": {
            "uuid": "abcd",
            "type": "strifn",
            "name": "default",
            "version": 3.12,
            "s3ObjectVersionId": "",
            "created": 165842829134
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "uuid": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "03504029-a029-417d-bd67-fb1b5fc5055b",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "agg": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "index",
                                    "_type": "doc",
                                    "_id": "9",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "uuid": "03504029-a029-417d-bd67-fb1b5fc5055b",
                                        "type": "gdsg",
                                        "discontinued": false,
                                        "version": 1.1,
                                        
                                        "created": 1554904300799
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1.1
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "794a5b8f-3e22-4ff9-98bb-b8b54c85948e",
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "agg": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 3,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "index",
                                    "_type": "doc",
                                    "_id": "7",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "uuid": "794a5b8f-3e22-4ff9-98bb-b8b54c85948e",
                                        "type": "qsdn",
                                        "discontinued": false,
                                        "minSupportedPlatformVersion": "11.5.3.3",
                                        "version": 2,
                                        "created": 1658428291346
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        2
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            ]
            }
    }
}
```

I am using AWS opensearch for the same

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct only, you just need to increase the size from 1 to see all the documents in your bucket sorted according to version field in your Elasticsearch index.

Can you share more info, if above doesn't help you, like sample documents and index mapping.

Comment: existing query is working properly to group by xyz and return the latest version. Now i need to sort the aggregated data based on created field
`
{
 "_index": "index",
 "_type": "doc",
 "_id": "3",
 "_version": 2,
 "_seq_no": 1,
 "_primary_term": 1,
 "found": true,
 "_source": {
  "doc": {
   "uuid": "abcd",
   "type": "strifn",
   "name": "event_viewer_executes_uncommon_binary.nwr",
   "version": 3.12,
   "s3ObjectVersionId": "lPL3v.4FwuKPew.Y.36lQQdeQEeIaAqP",
   "description": "",
   "created": 165842829134
  }
 }
}
`

Comment: @PuneetDewan i don't see the index mapping and sample and expected documents

Comment: @PuneetDewan, you justy added a single document, can you add few more and show your required result set out of those sample documents so that I can work on your data set

Comment: I have added what the current query returns. I need the hits in sorted format by created field

Comment: @PuneetDewan are you able to solve issue?